# how to enable only typed calls to a function in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics, inheritance, interface

I have some interfaces:

```
interface IBase {}
interface IXpto {}
interface ICorge extends IBase {}
```

And this hook:

```
export default function useLoadData<T extends IBase>(path: string) {

  const [entities, setEntities] = useState<T[]>([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    loadData();
  }, []);

  async function loadData() {
    setIsLoading(true);
    getJson(path)
      .then(setEntities)
      .finally(() => setIsLoading(false));
  }

  return {
    entities,
    isLoading,
  };
}
```

I want to allow only this type of call (T types that extend IBase):

```
const { entities } = useLoadData<ICorge>("ghi")
```

and I want untyped or wrongly typed calls to generate an error:

```
const { entities1 } = useLoadData("abc")
const { entities2 } = useLoadData<IXpto>("def")
```

even using this: `function useLoadData<T extends IBase>`, TS allows above calls to work

Comment: Have you tried adding anything to IBase yet? TS is structurally typed.

Comment: Your interfaces are all equivalent to each other and to the empty object type `{}`.  TypeScript’s type system is *structural* and not *nominal*. If you want to distinguish two object types, give them different members.

Comment: oh, I understand now. Can I keep IBase without members, just as a way to sort other interfaces that inherit from it? Example: `interface IBase {}; interface IBaseA extends IBase {a: number}; interface IBaseB extends IBase {b: string}`. And use what I mentioned?

Comment: No, you still need to add some discriminator so TS doesn't see `IBase` as simply `{}`. Almost all types are assignable to `{}`.